# How to get bind to base viewmodel from contextmenu inside treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I'm having trouble getting the selection in a contextMenu to bind to my command EditCommand. The buttons in my tree-view bind to it fine, but in the menu it fails. I have read this is most likely due to the contextMenu being in a different UI tree, but solutions using findAncestor and tags have not worked for me. Is there anyway to do bind and still be able to pass the treeViewItem to the method?

***My XAML:***

```
<TreeView Background="Transparent"
          Margin="10"
          Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TreeViewItems}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate >
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:TreeViewSelection}" ItemsSource="{Binding Configs}" >
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"><!--Transparency allows context click on whole row-->
                <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem 
                            Header="Edit"
                            Command="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.EditCommand}"<!--Doesn't work-->
                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                            <MenuItem.Icon>
                                <Image Source="../Images/edit.png" />
                            </MenuItem.Icon>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <Button Height="23" Width="23"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=userControl, Path=DataContext.EditCommand}"<!--Works-->
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Style="{DynamicResource ImageNoTextButton}"
                        inf:AttachedProperties.Image="../Images/edit.png"
                        inf:AttachedProperties.ImageMouseOver="../Images/editMouseOver.png" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

</TreeView>
```

Comment: How about binding to the relative source and searching for the ancestor by `Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.EditCommand, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"` ?

Comment: @Peter, the issue with that is i'm trying to bind to the UserControl data context (the view this snippet is in's view model)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"
           Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}">
    <DockPanel.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem 
                Header="Edit"
                Command="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag.DataContext.EditCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="../Images/edit.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DockPanel.ContextMenu>
    ...
</DockPanel>
```